Display lines & values for whole range of y-axis values in Kusto linechart
I have a kql script that creates the table at bottom and the line chart here:

Is it possible to display a line and/or the value for each y-axis value as in the below image? (extra lines and y-axis number values below were manually added using editor)

Query
myquery
| order by Date asc
| render linechart with ( 
    legend = hidden, title = myracer,
    // ymin=0, ymax=4,
    xcolumn=Place, xaxis=linear, xtitle="Location",
    ycolumns=Stage_Num,  ytitle="Stage"
)
;

Table



Display lines & values for whole range of y-axis values in Kusto linechart

To display lines and values in Y-axis, you need to drag the line towards up as shown below:
Before:

After:

